# Get deep elements by name in Javascript within another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML document with multiple div tags like

```
<div id="id1">
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Serial</th>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><input id="Param1" name="Group1" type="text" value ="0"/></td>
            <td><input id="Param2" name="Group1" type="text" value ="0"/></td>


        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input id="Param3" name="Group2" type="text" value ="0"/></td>
            <td><input id="Param4" name="Group2" type="text" value ="0"/></td>


        </tr>

    </table>

</div>

<div id="id2">

...
...

</div>
```

How can I select the inputs that have div id as "id1" and make an array of input ids that have name "Group1" using either Javascript OR jQuery?

Comment: You're asking for the selector `#id1 input[name=Group1]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery, you can use the [descendant](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) and [attribute equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selectors.

```
$("#id1 [name='Group1']");
```

using just plain old vanilla JavaScript without any libraries using [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll):

```
document.querySelectorAll("#id1 [name='Group1']");
```

[**Try it out on jsFiddle!**](http://jsfiddle.net/adamzr/PnXwP/)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean inputs inside the div with an id of `id1`? If so:

```
var inputs = $('#id1 input[name="Group1"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var inputs = $('#id1 input[name="Group1"]');
```

**Demo** [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/xz7n8/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using find() : **[DEMO HERE:](http://jsfiddle.net/charaf11/jTpHN/)**

```
 var array = $('div#id1').find('input[name="Group1"]') ;
```

Or using a simple selector like this :

```
var array = $('div#id1 input[name="Group1"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with jquery as,

```
var resultArray = $("div#id input[name='Group1']")
```

And in javascript as,

```
document.getElementById("id1").getElementsByName("Group1")
```

Comment: This answer was exactly like the one that got deleted. Sorry, -1.

Comment: yah it is pretty much same! I think because it is the only answer we have for that question :D!

Comment: So this means we cannot use native Javascript without jQuery to accomplish this?